# Using iText how to design custom Table

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I'm using iText library to generate pdf document and got stuck in designing nested table.Can anyone please advice me.

How i want my Pdf file

[image]

How it looks

[image]

I'm attaching my code snippet also where i'm creating the pdf.Please have a look and adivice me in completing it.Thanks in advance!!!

Code:

```
    double transTotal = 0.00;
    int transQty = 0;
    double tax = 0.00;
    double preTax = 0.00;
    double netTot = 0.00;
    double discount = 0.00;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    try {

        File pdfFolder = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + "Android/AMSP", "TransactionReport(" + date
                        + ")");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.i("", "Pdf Directory created");
        }

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder, "TranReport" + ".pdf");
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                new File(myFile.getAbsolutePath())));

        Font font1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 50, Font.BOLD
                | Font.UNDERLINE);
        Font font2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 18, Font.ITALIC);
        Font font3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20);
        Font bfBold12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD,
                new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
        Font bf12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
        document.open();

        String[] datearr = (String[]) date.split("-");
        int mYear = Integer.parseInt(datearr[2]);
        int mMonth = Integer.parseInt(datearr[1]);
        int mDay = Integer.parseInt(datearr[0]);

        dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        tempTransOrdListRef = dbHelper.getDistinctRefTransNoList(mDay,
                mYear, mMonth);
        dbHelper.closeDatabase();

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
        paragraph1.add("Company Name");
        paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph1.setFont(font1);
        document.add(paragraph1);

        Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
        paragraph2.add("Company Address");
        paragraph2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph2.setFont(font2);
        document.add(paragraph2);

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph();
        paragraph3.add("Sales Person: ");
        paragraph3.setFont(font3);
        document.add(paragraph3);

        Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph();
        paragraph4.add("Date: " + date);
        paragraph4.setFont(font3);
        document.add(paragraph4);

        document.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        for (int i = 0; i < tempTransOrdListRef.size(); i++)// Total
                                                            // number of
                                                            // invoices
        {
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.setFont(font3);

            // specify column widths
            float[] columnWidths = { 2.5f, 5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.7f, 1.8f };
            // create PDF table with the given widths
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
            // set table width a percentage of the page width
            table.setWidthPercentage(90f);

            //insert an empty row
               insertCell(table, "", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 6, bfBold12);
               //create section heading by cell merging
               insertCell(table, "Ref No: "+tempTransOrdListRef.get(i)
                        .getHhTran_referenceNumber(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT,6, bfBold12);
               double orderTotal, total = 0;


            // insert column headings
            insertCell(table, "Item Number", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1,
                    bfBold12);
            insertCell(table, "Item Description", Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                    1, bfBold12);
            insertCell(table, "Qty", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
            insertCell(table, "UOM", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bfBold12);
            insertCell(table, "External Price", Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    1, bfBold12);
            insertCell(table, "Location", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1,
                    bfBold12);

            table.setHeaderRows(1);

            dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            tempTransOrdListDateWise = dbHelper
                    .getTransactionExportOrderListDateWise(mDay,
                            mMonth, mYear, tempTransOrdListRef.get(i)
                                    .getHhTran_referenceNumber());
            dbHelper.closeDatabase();
            System.out.println("RefNum:"
                    + tempTransOrdListRef.get(i)
                            .getHhTran_referenceNumber());
            for (int j = 0; j < tempTransOrdListDateWise.size(); j++) {// No
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // items

                insertCell(table, tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_itemNumber(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1,
                        bf12);

                // For Description
                dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                HhItem01 hhItem01 = dbHelper.getItemData(
                        tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                                .getHhTran_itemNumber(),
                        tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(i)
                                .getHhTran_locId());
                dbHelper.closeDatabase();

                insertCell(table, hhItem01.getHhItem_description(),
                        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12);

                insertCell(table, tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_qty() + "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1,
                        bf12);
                insertCell(table, tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_uom(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bf12);
                insertCell(table, tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_extPrice() + "",
                        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, bf12);
                insertCell(table, tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_locId(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1,
                        bf12);

                String strTransTot = tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_extPrice() + "";
                String strQty = tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_qty() + "";
                String itemNumb = tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_itemNumber();
                String strDiscount = tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                        .getHhTran_discPrice() + "";

                double cTot = Double.parseDouble(strTransTot);
                transTotal = transTotal + cTot;

                // to calculate qty
                int cQty = Integer.parseInt(strQty);
                transQty = transQty + cQty;

                // to calculate
                double cDiscount = Double.parseDouble(strDiscount);
                discount = discount + cDiscount;

                // to calculate tax
                dbHelper.openReadableDatabase();
                double cTax = getTax((cTot - cDiscount), itemNumb,
                        tempTransOrdListDateWise.get(j)
                                .getHhTran_customerNumber());
                dbHelper.closeDatabase();

                tax = tax + cTax;

            }       

            paragraph.add(table);               
            document.add(paragraph);


            netTot = transTotal + tax + preTax - discount;

            /*Paragraph OrderTotal = new Paragraph();
            OrderTotal.add("OrderTotal: "); 
            OrderTotal.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            OrderTotal.setFont(bfBold12);
            document.add(OrderTotal);                   
            Paragraph OrderTotal_Value = new Paragraph();
            OrderTotal_Value.add(supporter.getCurrencyFormat(transTotal));      
            OrderTotal_Value.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            OrderTotal_Value.setFont(bf12);
            document.add(OrderTotal_Value);



            Paragraph Discount = new Paragraph();
            Discount.add("Discount: ");
            Discount.setFont(bfBold12);
            Discount.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            document.add(Discount);
            Paragraph Discount_Value = new Paragraph();
            Discount_Value.add(supporter.getCurrencyFormat(transTotal));        
            Discount_Value.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            Discount_Value.setFont(bf12);
            document.add(Discount_Value);

            Paragraph TotalQty = new Paragraph();
            TotalQty.add("Total Qty: ");
            TotalQty.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            TotalQty.setFont(bfBold12);
            document.add(TotalQty);
            Paragraph TotalQty_Value = new Paragraph();
            TotalQty_Value.add(transQty+"");        
            TotalQty_Value.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            TotalQty_Value.setFont(bf12);
            document.add(TotalQty_Value);

            Paragraph Tax = new Paragraph();
            Tax.add("Tax: ");
            Tax.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Tax.setFont(bfBold12);
            document.add(Tax);
            Paragraph Tax_Value = new Paragraph();
            Tax_Value.add(supporter.getCurrencyFormat(tax));        
            Tax_Value.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            Tax_Value.setFont(bf12);
            document.add(Tax_Value);

            Paragraph NetAmount = new Paragraph();
            NetAmount.add("NetAmount: ");
            NetAmount.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            NetAmount.setFont(bfBold12);
            document.add(NetAmount);
            Paragraph NetAmount_Value = new Paragraph();
            NetAmount_Value.add( supporter.getCurrencyFormat(netTot));      
            NetAmount_Value.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            NetAmount_Value.setFont(bf12);
            document.add(NetAmount_Value);*/



            document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            }

    } catch (DocumentException dex) {
        dex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            // close the document
            document.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            // close the writer
            writer.close();
        }

    }
    return "success";
```

Comment: You are using iText 5 and your code is very hard to read. You'd make it much easier on yourself if you'd start using iText 7. Creating custom tables is much easier when using iText 7. See [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) of the [iText 7: building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference.